# Why is pip editable install causing issue with subpackages?

Tags: python, pip, python-import, setuptools, setup.py

### The Problem

I'm having an issue using editable install for my package. Inside my package I have three subpackages as shown in my setup.py file. Everything works fine if I install with `pip install .`, but if I install with `pip install -e .` then I'll get the following error when attempting to run the CLI `relctl`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_username/.virtualenvs/rawp3/bin/relctl", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('tech-control', 'console_scripts', 'relctl')()
  File "/Users/my_username/.virtualenvs/rawp3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/my_username/.virtualenvs/rawp3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2859, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/my_username/.virtualenvs/rawp3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2450, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Users/my_username/.virtualenvs/rawp3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2456, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tech_control.cli'
```

On further inspection I find that I'm not able to import any subpackages. E.g. The following will fail:
`import tech_control.boards`
Fails with: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tech_control.boards'`

### My Package Directory

```
tech_control/
├── __init__.py
├── boards
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── board_base.py
│   ├── tech8ch.py
│   └── wiring.py
├── cli
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── cli.py
└── setup.py
```

### Setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="tech_control",
    version="0.1.0",
    description="CLI for Tech Boards",
    packages=["tech_control", "tech_control.boards", "tech_control.cli"],
    package_dir={
        "tech_control": "",
        "tech_control.boards": "boards",
        "tech_control.cli": "cli"},
    install_requires=["pyusb"],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "relctl = tech_control.cli.cli:main"
        ]
    },
)
```

### Question

Why is my editable install preventing me from accessing subpackages?

Comment: I don't think editable installations can deal with changes in the directory structure as done by `package_dir`.

Comment: You could try something like `package_dir={'': '..'}` but no guarantee it would work, it might go quite wrong, I would not recommend it anyway.

Comment: Is there a way I can change my directory structure so it will handle it and I can maintain the namespace I've setup? E.g. `from tech_control.boards import X`

Comment: Nothing comes to mind. This is an unusual directory structure.

Comment: As far as I know, _editable_ installations keep the directory structure. So make your source code directory structure the same as the _importable_ package structure, and it should be fine.

Comment: That's fair. I got rid of the package_dir as you suggested and it works. Your comment is the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, *editable* installations do not work with changes to the directory structure, as done with `package_dir`.

Changing the root directory is OK, though:

```
package_dir={'': 'path/to/root'}
```

**References**:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3160
- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/463
- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/230
- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html?highlight=package_dir#listing-whole-packages
- https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/examples.html?highlight=package_dir#pure-python-distribution-by-package
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=package_dir#using-find-packages
- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=package_dir#using-a-src-layout

**Aside**:

There is currently an ongoing effort towards a new design for *editable* installations. Most likely the combination with the rewrite of the directory structure is probably not in scope, as it's probably not a use case that comes up often enough to make it worth the additional code complexity to support this.

- https://discuss.python.org/t/next-steps-for-editable-develop-proof-of-concept/4118
- https://discuss.python.org/t/standardising-editable-mode-installs-runtime-layout-not-hooks/4098
- https://discuss.python.org/t/third-try-on-editable-installs/3986